# Oriented point (XYZ+Yaw/Pitch/Roll) frame to frame transform

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

I have a 3D oriented point (XYZ + Yaw/Pitch/Roll).  Lets say this point is based on "user frame 1" (UF1)(the frame is defined in relation to the world frame (WF)).

I also have another "user frame", lets call it "user frame 2" (UF2) that is also defined in reference to the world frame.

How would I take my 3d oriented point (6 coordinates; 3 location + 3 rotation) from one frame to another ?

For example; Since all user frame are related to the world frame, How would I calculate (transform) my 3d oriented point from UF1 to WF ?  Or vice-versa or from any combination ? (UF1->WF, WF->UF2, etc.)

The resulting point must have the 6 coordinates (3 location + 3 rotation) in relation to the destination frame.

PS: I'm mainly working in C#, so if possible code sample or pseudo-code to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you call "frame"? Can you draw your problem? It would help understand

Comment: A "frame" would be a "coordinate system".  The "world frame" would be "0, 0, 0" and all angles at "0".  User frame 1 could be for example at coordinate "5,10,15" and have different angle of rotation, thus defining another "coordinate system" (defined in relation to the world frame, the world coordinate system)...  Does this make more sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the transition matrix from one coordinate system to an other.

It is a 4x4 matrix fully determined by the 3 parameters of translation and the 6 angles of ratotion between the 2 coordinate system.

The 9 coefficients depend on the rotation angles (Euler angles or quaternion depending on what you are using). Be aware that if you are using Euler angles, **the order is important** : a vector of rotation (rx, ry, rz) does not describe the same rotation if you turn around X axis first then Y then Z or if you turn first around Z, then Y then X for example.

[image]

I suggest you read this, it will help you compute the matrix:
http://brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html

Note that all this is using homogenous coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  (And sorry for the delay in responding)  I'll go study the link you provided and advance a bit further into my application and see if it gives me the information I require.  Thanks!